# D3.js creating a link on legend which highlights only that data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made this scatterplot and now i want to know how to link the legends and the data so that when i click on one legend i only want to see those values.

I tried on.click but i need to know how to link the data to the click function. I need to know how to do that. Please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Example based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118 -->
<!-- Tooltip example from http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html -->

<style>
body {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* 
 * value accessor - returns the value to encode for a given data object.
 * scale - maps value to a visual display encoding, such as a pixel position.
 * map function - maps from data value to display value
 * axis - sets up axis
 */ 

// setup x 
var xValue = function(d) { return d.Day;}, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 200]), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

// setup y
var yValue = function(d) { return d.Hour;}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

// setup fill color
var cValue = function(d) { return d.name;},
    color = d3.scale.category10();

// add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// load data
d3.csv("11.csv", function(error, data) {

  // change string (from CSV) into number format
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Hour = +d.Hour;
    d.Day = +d.Day;
//    console.log(d);
  });

  // don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
  xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue)-1, d3.max(data, xValue)+1]);
  yScale.domain([d3.min(data, yValue)-1, d3.max(data, yValue)+1]);

  // x-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("id", "blueLine")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Hour");

  // y-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("id", "redLine")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Day");

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr()
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .5);
          tooltip.html(d.name + "<br/> (" + xValue(d) 
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });

  // draw legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);
      .on("click", function(d){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true,
          newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        blueLine.active = active;
    })

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 250)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return d;})

  d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
      var selected = this.value;
      display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";


  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.name;})
      .attr("display", display);
      });

  d3.selectAll("[name=Day]").on("change", function(d) {
     radius = this.value;

     svg.selectAll(".dot")
     console.log(radius);
     circles.attr("r", function(d) { return d[radius]; });
  });

  d3.select("[name=xAX]").on("change", function(){
    xAxy = this.value;
    console.log(xAxy)
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[xAxy]; })).nice();

    svg.select(".x.axis").transition().call(xAxis);

    svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cx", function(d) { 
        return x(d[xAxy]);
    });
    svg.selectAll(".x.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[xAxy] + " (cm)");
  });

  d3.select("[name=yAX]").on("change", function(){
    yAxy = this.value;
    console.log(yAxy)
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[yAxy]; })).nice();
    svg.select(".y.axis").transition().call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cy", function(d) { 
        return y(d[yAxy]);
    });
    svg.selectAll(".y.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[yAxy] + " (cm)");
  });
});

</script>
<br><br>

<! Filters for the error names>
  <div id="filter">
    <b>Filter:</b>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Completed Users vs RedemeedCodes vs Redemeption SMS" type="checkbox" checked>Completed Users vs RedemeedCodes vs Redemeption SMS
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Error_Log" type="checkbox" checked >Error_Log
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="CompletedUsers_AcknowledgeSMS" type="checkbox" checked >CompletedUsers_AcknowledgeSMS
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="OBD MissedCall Time_Lag" type="checkbox" checked>OBD MissedCall Time_Lag

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Denied Permission Calls SMS Sent" type="checkbox" checked>Denied Permission Calls SMS Sent

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Domex Tableau Refresh Fail" type="checkbox" checked>Domex Tableau Refresh Fail

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Non IVR Entries in SMS Transactions" type="checkbox" checked>Non IVR Entries in SMS Transactions

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Non Kannada Transactions" type="checkbox" checked>Non Kannada Transactions

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Non OBD Entries in IVR Transactions" type="checkbox" checked>Non OBD Entries in IVR Transactions

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Unique MissCallers vs Firsttime OBDs" type="checkbox" checked>Unique MissCallers vs Firsttime OBDs

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="UniqueCallers vs Firsttime OBDs" type="checkbox" checked>UniqueCallers vs Firsttime OBDs

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="User Current Position" type="checkbox" checked>User Current Position

    </input>
    <br>
    <input name="v" value="UniqueCallers vs Firsttime OBDs
" type="checkbox" checked>UniqueCallers vs Firsttime OBDs

    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="UniqueCallers_FirstOBDs" type="checkbox" checked>UniqueCallers_FirstOBDs

    </input>
  </div>
  <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update the line 93? `.attr("d", )`

Comment: I can't run your example because of the missing data but you could adjust the opacity on the dots according to color of the dots, e.g. `legend. .... .on("click", function (d, i, e) { var currColor = d; dots.attr("opacity", function(d){ return d.somethingInDots' data is equal to currColor? 1: 0; })})` (possibly something a bit more elaborate than this in order to be able to remove the filter etc). Hope this helps! Good luck!